# RegQueryValueEx giving strange data

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, registry

```
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
TCHAR keyData[1024];
DWORD keyDataLength = 1024;
cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME; 
achValue[0] = '\0';     
HKEY currentKey;
long err = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), NULL, KEY_READ, &currentKey);
_tprintf(TEXT("OpenKey Error Code: %d\n"), err);
err = RegQueryValueEx(currentKey, TEXT("STEAM"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&keyData, &keyDataLength);
_tprintf(TEXT("QueryKey Error Code: %d\n"), err);
_tprintf(TEXT("Data: %d\n"), keyData);
```

The code above produces the following result:

```
OpenKey Error Code: 0
QueryKey Error Code: 0
Data: 15332432
```

How can I get the keyData to display the proper result? I've looked online for quite a while and this is almost a duplicate of working examples I found online... It is set for UNICODE and I do not want to switch the charset.

Comment: What is `MAX_VALUE_NAME` set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keyData` is an array of `TCHAR`. try to print the char array with `%s`.

```
 _tprintf(TEXT("Data: %s\n"), keyData);
                    //^^^ not %d
```

**EDIT**
Thanks `@Windows programmer`

In addition, `keyDataLength` is supposed to count bytes, so it should be either `1024 * sizeof(TCHAR)` or more simply `sizeof(keyData)`.

Comment: Yes.  In addition, keyDataLength is supposed to count bytes, so it should be either 1024 * sizeof(TCHAR) or more simply sizeof keyData.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer Thanks for pointing that out, I did not notice that when I looked at the print output.